# facebook web request from asp.net to fetch albums

Tags: asp.net

Greetings!
I am trying to fetch list of albums from my facebook account from my asp.net application.
For this i am using facebookapi and it creats web request for following url:

http://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?access_token=201397309875468%7C2.zOxG70QX1tAV3necYGWJ5A__.3600.1297328400-100000682028927%7C2Y-eRXd5fxhGi7gdvZWFem0nRNU

But it returns 0 albums. I have 2 albums in my account.
When i triend to fetch my friends list then it returned me all my friends with their ids.

If someone has idea about this then please give me suggestion to handle this.

Thanks 
Munish

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in looking at facebook's developer wiki, they have allot of information regarding their API, although i have never tried this yet i know some of my friends created similar applications and works like you.And all of what they have got everything from Facebooks wiki for developers.